# How to execute application from PHP async

Tags: php, windows, spawn

When I'm using `exec` or `shell_exec` they wait until the spawned app will exit (in Windows). But I need to run and forget (and exit). How?

I tried `start` DOS/Windows command but did not find the solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$shell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$shell->run($command, 0, false);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll add a link to your answer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.85).aspx